# Get all topics that publish a given message?

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to get the names of all topics that publish a given message?
E.g. when I add an image viewer in RVIZ, it already lists for you all topics that publish a `sensor_msgs/Image` message, so you choose which one you want to subscribe to! How can I achieve something like this in C++?
Say I have a message called A, I want to get the names of all topics that publish A. Appreciate any help or suggestions:-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367551/get-all-topics-that-publish-a-given-message?/) by [Martian](https://answers.ros.org/users/38114/martian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apologies if this is the wrong part of the rviz code that does what you're asking, but I think what you're looking for is `ros::master::getTopics()` which is used here https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/3cdc03a5186a53f644c5abd55b9971457bdffa1c/src/rviz/add_display_dialog.cpp#L124 in `rviz` to get the list of topics and add them to the display for drop downs (~85% sure this is the right thing, but it was a quick glance, either way this will do what you're asking).

Here's the API docs for that file http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/roscpp/html/master_8h.html and it clearly shows the basic "get info" style calls to get all the topics and nodes on the network graph.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martian](https://answers.ros.org/users/38114/martian/) on 2020-12-12**:
These links are more than enough for my question to be answered! Thanks a lot for the references:-)